# *** Exception: stack overflow : Stack overflow

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and I am getting an exception "stack overflow" I was not expecting.

The code is fairly simple:

```
type Reals = Double

prod :: Reals -> Reals -> Reals
prod a b = a*b

coprod :: Reals -> Reals -> Reals
coprod a b = a + b - (prod a b)

newsum :: Reals -> Reals -> Int -> Reals
newsum a b n =   
    approxA!!n 
    where
      approxA = a : zipWith coprod approxA approxB 
      approxB = b : zipWith prod approxA approxB
```

The functions prod, coprod are intended to be evalated on reals in [0,1]. The function

> newsum a b n

for n going to infinity, computes the function (a,b) -> min(1, a+b).

You can try

> newsum 0.5 0.5 10

and

> newsum 0.5 0.5 10000

to see this. However, by calling

> newsum 0.5 0.5 10000000

I get a stack overflow. The newsum function is simple and makes a linear (in n) number of operations of Double type. In other words, the construction n-th element of the(infinite) lists of type [Reals]

> approxA

and

> approxB

takes linear time.

QUESTION 1: Why am I getting the stack overflow? |
What are the limits of Haskell (or GHCi) and how can I estimate them (in advance) in a simple program like the one above?

QUESTION 2: Is there a flag/command in Haskell to instruct the interpreter to page the memory automatically, if needed? I want to write code that resemble Math, and don't want to spend time thinking about memory limits, stack overflows and stuff like that.

thanks!

Comment: Stick to a single question at a time, please. (Though, this looks almost exactly like the scenario discussed here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Stack_overflow)

Comment: "I want to write code that resemble Math, and don't want to spend time thinking about memory limits, stack overflows and stuff like that." Programming doesn't work this way. Unless you are happy to get your answer in one of the coming millennia, that is.

Comment: [Doesn't reproduce](https://ideone.com/2DOVTf). Try compiling your code rather than loading the source to GHCi.

Comment: The question asks specifically about GHCi. And I think it's reasonable for op to want their code here to Just Work, after all that's what your suggestion to compile with optimizations is essentially.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `(!!)` is lazy: it doesn't force earlier values in the list to be evaluated, so `ghci` ends up with a huge expression for the nth item, which overflows its stack.

You can increase the stack size with run time options, eg for a 16GB stack:

```
$ ghci +RTS -K16G
> newsum 0.5 0.5 10000000
0.9999999000001789
```

But if you exceed the memory available to your system (which can include virtual memory / swap pages), you will have problems (here the Linux OOM killer struck me down):

```
> newsum 0.5 0.5 100000000
Killed
$
```

This can be fixed in practice by writing a function that forces each head of the list to be evaluated before its tail can be accessed:

```
strict :: [a] -> [a]
strict [] = []
strict (x:xs) = seq x (x : strict xs)
```

`seq x y` forces `x` to be evaluated (to WHNF, which for `Double` means fully-evaluated) when the value of `y` is demanded.
Use `strict` like this:

```
newsum' :: Reals -> Reals -> Int -> Reals
newsum' a b n =
    strict approxA!!n
    where
      approxA = a : zipWith coprod approxA approxB
      approxB = b : zipWith prod approxA approxB
```

Now it runs in small constant memory.

An alternative is to use a stricter data structure (the `!a` is a strict `a`):

```
data List' a = !a :! List' a
```

but then you need to reimplement `(!!)` and `zipWith` for this type.

Comment: thanks, I now understand why lazyness 'creates' a huge expression in this case, and how Seq can solve this.
Thansk man! very useful answer!

Comment: thanks again for your previous answer. However I have a doubt now. 
Running GHCi with the flag ":set +s" to see execution time and memory usage, I see that the program newsum' is still using a linear (in n) amount of memory: try 10000, 100000 and 1000000. How is this possible? How can I really get a constant-space function ?

Thanks!

Comment: @makkiato `:set +s` outputs total allocations over the whole evaluation, not peak memory usage (I use `top` or `htop` in another terminal to visualize that)

Comment: @makkiato the difference between the versions, is that the strict one can garbage collect the allocations as it goes along, instead of only at the very end